# Why does Pink's gem look different from the mural?

Tags: steven-universe

As most people know by now, Pink Diamond

> was the same as "Rose Quartz."

As such, her gemstone looked like this, when not rotated:

[image]

However, her mural shows her as having the same diamond-shaped gemstone as the other Diamonds.

[image]

Having seen the other Diamonds, we know that the mural, though stylized, is accurate to their appearances, in particular the location and shape of their gemstones. It is for Pink, too, even down to her Gem placement—except for the shape of her gemstone.

Why is this?

Comment: May wanna put the "when not rotated" in spoiler tags as well (or just remove it, since it's not relevant to the question).

Comment: I think in that particular image you might be able to claim that her leg is lifted up far enough to obscure a portion of her gem, making it *look* like a diamond when in fact it is not.  The angles on the "far" side don't seem quite consistent with this, but perhaps "leg yielding optical illusion + maybe slight animation error" is preferable to "animation error/retcon".

Comment: @zibdawa - It's no recon. They definitely knew where they were going by that point.

Answer (score 3):

### 1) (in-universe) the mural is a stylized / symbolic image

As such, it is **not** "accurate to their appearances, in particular the location and shape of their gemstones".

The four diamonds are depicted having identical, rhombus-shaped gems that match the shapes composing the old Diamond Authority symbol, representing (just my guess) harmony, order, stability, ...

[image: Diamond Authority]

<sub>(image from [Steven Universe Wikia](http://steven-universe.wikia.com/wiki/The_Great_Diamond_Authority#Earthlings_034-png))</sub>

But the real gems (not only Rose's one) are different:

[image: Yellow Diamond's gem]
[image: Blue Diamond's gem]

<sub>(images from [Steven Universe Wikia](http://steven-universe.wikia.com))</sub>

[image]

<sub>(image from [Tumblr](https://78.media.tumblr.com/0d325f2338ee5bd5743a26d8fa4ce80e/tumblr_pc8z53pRmH1vmuj5so2_1280.jpg), could not find the original post)</sub>

### 2) (out-of-universe) the mural was based on old designs, subsequently revised.

Note that, apart from Yellow Diamond, *all* the diamonds' appearances are quite different from their final design (for example, Blue Diamond's hair is dark instead of white and lacks the "coil" around her neck).

While the authors had the general *story* in mind from the get-go, the character *designs* were not finalized until they actually had to appear in the episodes.

In a [Tumblr post](http://joethejohnston.tumblr.com/post/173776256458/why-does-pinks-physical-form-not-match-her-mural) dated May 10th 2018, storyboarder Joe Johnston answered a very similar question:

> **Why does Pink's physical form not match her mural?**
>
> I drew those murals way before the Diamonds designs were finalized.
>   Yellow was pretty figured out because her appearance had at that point already been storyboarded.
>   Rebecca had done some very rough drawings of Blue, _____ and Pink and I was basing the murals off of those drawings.
>   When it came time to really design Pink, Rebecca chose to alter her hair and such, but not so far that the mural didn’t look completely wrong.

(the redacted name clearly is

> White Diamond

which at that time hadn't been explicitly mentioned yet in the aired episodes)

Answer (score 2):

A quick MS-Paint later:

[image: Proposal: That's her fore leg lifted up, obscuring the gem]

There's not a lot of detail on the image telling us which leg is closer to the viewer, and in particular if the lifted leg is closer than the gem is.  But supposing the lifted leg is in fact the closest leg to us (marked with the orange lines in the picture), then we would be led to believe that we are only seeing part of her gem.  That the visible portion appears to be a classic diamond shape is an illusion.  Highlighting the borders of the visible portion in a pink color, I've filled in a very rough idea of the outline of the hidden portions of the gem.  The sizes and angles are a tad off (the bottom-left visible edge seems too long, for example), though whether this is because I'm bad as MS-paint rush-jobs, or a slight error in the animation, the animators and/or I not quite taking proper account of angles (the hidden portion should be receding away from us, since we are looking at the rest of her torso from the side), an unexpected exercise of in-universe artistic license (or guessing because maybe a sculptor isn't worthy of looking at a Diamond up-close), or evidence that my assumption of which leg is in front is wrong, is hard for me to say.

The closest thing to a side-on view of Pink Diamond I can recall is in the following scene:
[image: pink smash stupid mirror]